# How to find operators like equal, less than and greater than?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

When I try to find the below line in a txt file, the error is shown

> FINDSTR: Cannot open value="e app46707.xml

How to escape the equal (`=`) sign in a file?

```
FINDSTR "id type=\^"eLocator\^" value=\^"e" app46707.txt
```

app46707.txt

```
<idGroup>
<id type="unit" value="APP46707"/>
<id type="eLocator" value="e46707"/>
</idGroup>
```

Comment: Did you try escaping the doublequotes in your match string with just the backslash, instead of a backslash followed by a caret?

Comment: Why not use a scripting language that has a native method to read and write XML files.

Comment: please provide sample sir?

Comment: @Karthick use powershell. It's built-in and has native methods to operate on xml files

Answer (score 1):

Inside quoted strings `^` doesn't work as the escape character<sup>1</sup>. Therefore you don't need to escape twice with `\^`, only `\` is enough (in this case). When you run your command then 2 arguments will be passed to `FINDSTR`: `id type=\^eLocator"` and  `value="e app46707.txt`

That's why you see the

> FINDSTR: Cannot open value="e app46707.txt

error, as there's no file named `value="e app46707.txt`. Besides `FINDSTR` searches for multiple words by default. `FINDSTR "abc xyz"` will find any lines that contain "abc" or "xyz". To find a literal string with spaces you must use the `/C:` option. After fixing all of the above points then the command will work as expected

```
D:\>FINDSTR /c:"id type=\"eLocator\" value=\"e" app46707.txt
<id type="eLocator" value="e46707"/>
```

---

But that way it's highly fragile, because it'll break when more spaces or tabs are inserted in the xml tag, or `"` is changed to `'`, or the tag is broken into multiple lines. Moreover escaping in cmd is a mess that's difficult to fix. PowerShell has far more regular quoting rules, and it supports everything that's available in .NET framework, so it already has native capability to parse xml files. Just use [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-6) which will return the node based on an [XPath query](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

```
PS D:\> Select-Xml -Path .\app46707.txt -XPath '//id[@type="eLocator"]'

Node Path            Pattern
---- ----            -------
id   D:\app46707.txt //id[@type="eLocator"]
```

---

<sup>1</sup>From [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/995714)

> If it is a quote (`"`) toggle the quote flag, if the quote flag is active, the following special characters are no longer special: `^ & | < > ( )`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
findstr /s /i /n /p /c:"=" *app46707.txt*
```

Comment: you're finding all lines with `=` instead of lines with the type attribute